# How can I optimize searching in one file by using values from another one?

Tags: perl, search, hash

I have two kind of files, lets say file A and file B.
The file A has lines like this

```
scaffold10920   13740   14020   chr19.3.4051.27470346.27470626  280     100.00
```

The file B has lines like this

```
283     2       0       0       0       0       0       0       +       chr16.1.1.10933.11218   285     0       285     scaffold476     838469  193881  194166  1       285,    0,   193881,
```

The previous examples are one line from each file. All the fields in both of the two files are tab-separated.

I want to filter the file B by keeping only the lines that have the same values with the first and fourth fields in file A (eg `scaffold10920` and `chr19.3.4051.27470346.27470626`). To do that, I made a hash table for file A like this

```
{chr19.3.4051.27470346.27470626} -->  scaffold10920
```

and I'm searching it in File B.

Here is my script:

```
#!/app/languages/perl/5.14.2/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $chromosome = $ARGV[0];
my @mykeys     = `cat rightChromosome/$chromosome.scaffolds.txt| sort -u`;

my %hces_hash;
foreach my $key_line (@mykeys) {

    #$key_line = $_;
    chomp($key_line);
    my @token = split('\t', $key_line);
    my $hce   = $token[3];
    my $scaff = $token[0];
    $hces_hash{$hce} = $scaff;
}

#print Dumper(\%hces_hash);

foreach my $key (keys %hces_hash) {

    chomp($key);

    my $scaffold = $hces_hash{$key};

    my $command  = "cat psl_best/$chromosome.best.psl|grep -w $key";
    my @belongs  = `$command`;
    chomp(@belongs);

    my $count = scalar(@belongs);

    foreach my $element (@belongs) {

        my @element_token = split('\t', $element);
        my $scaff_psl     = $element_token[13];
        my $hce_name      = $element_token[9];

        if ($scaffold eq $scaff_psl) {

            #print "$element\n";
            open FILE, ">>psl_raw/$chromosome.best.raw.psl" or die $!;
            print FILE "$element\n";
        }
    }
```

My script is working, but it is very slow. Is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: So fields 10 and 14 in file B have to match fields 4 and 1 of any of the records in file A. And `rightChromosome/$chromosome.scaffolds.txt` is file A, and `psl_best/$chromosome.best.psl` is file B. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  File A (field 4 as a key, field 1 as a value) must match with the file B (fields 10 and 14).

Comment: `grep` (the *nix utility, not to be confused with Perl's built-in [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)) will read every single line in your file. When you call `grep` in a loop, you're reading every line of your file, multiple times. This is very inefficient. As Borodin points out below, there's no need to shell out to an external command like `grep` to read from a file when you can do the same thing with pure Perl. As an aside, `cat file | grep foo` is better written as `grep foo file`.

Comment: Load the data into SQLite tables. Use SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work much faster, as it reads each file only once. I haven't been able to test it as I have no data, but I have checked that it compiles. You may want to change the names of some of the variables, but I have made my best guess.

It works by building the hash with keys that are *both* field 1 and field 4 of the *scaffolds* file with a tab between them. The hash value is irrelevant - just a positive number. Then it reads through the *best* file and builds the same key from fields 14 and 10, and simply checks whether that appears in the hash before printing the record to the output file.

You shouldn't shell out of Perl to do simple things like reading a file. It is necessary only when you need to do something that is beyond Perl's capabilities. I didn't see any point at all in the `sort` call as it is just taking time to order data that will become unordered again once it is stored in the hash.

```
#!/app/languages/perl/5.14.2/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

our @ARGV = qw/ chr2 /;

chdir 'psl_files';

my $raw_dir = 'psl_raw';

if ( -e $raw_dir ) {
  die qq{Can't make "$raw_dir"\n} unless -d $raw_dir;
  # ' fix highlighting
}
else {
  mkdir $raw_dir;
}

my ($chromosome) = @ARGV or die "Usage: $0 <chromosome>\n";

my $scaff_file = "rightChromosome/$chromosome.scaffolds.txt";
my $best_file  = "psl_best/$chromosome.best.psl";
my $raw_file   = "psl_raw/$chromosome.best.raw.psl";

# For provided data
$scaff_file = "chr2.scaffolds.txt";
$best_file  = "chr2.best_noHeaded.psl";

open my $scaff_fh, '<', $scaff_file;
my %hces_hash;
while ( <$scaff_fh> ) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /\t/;
  my $key = join "\t", @fields[0,3];
  ++$hces_hash{$key};
}
close $scaff_fh;

open my $best_fh, '<', $best_file;
open my $raw_fh,  '>', $raw_file;
while ( <$best_fh> ) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /\t/;
  my $key = join "\t", @fields[13,9];
  print $raw_fh "$_\n" if $hces_hash{$key};
}
close $raw_fh;
close $best_fh;
```

Comment: No, Unfortunately not.
It generates the file but It is not right. Also it gives me errors:
"Use of uninitialized value in join or string at ./pslRaw_new_version_2.pl line 28, <$_[...]> line 1."

Comment: Then either your data file contains records that are unlike the ones you have shown or, most likely, the fields are not tab-separated. If you cannot find the problem then put a sample of your data files on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) and give me the link so that I can work on it myself. You can put `say scalar @fields;` after line 27 to see how many fields the line is being split into

Comment: I solved the warning messages. It doesn't complains now, but I cannot understand why the outputs are different. Can I send you the two files in the drop box? I'm not so familiar with the pastebin.

Comment: I may not get back to you quickly. It's 10:30pm in England

Comment: Yes, I understand. I'm in UK, too. :)
There is no rush. Lets leave it for tomorrow.
Thank you very much

Comment: Your name sounded Greek. Post the link now please, then I can get to it when I'm available

Comment: You are right, I'm Greek but I leave in UK

Here is the link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yr381p1m9zvbri2/psl_files.zip?dl=0

Thank you very much, again.

Comment: @Vasilis: My program works with your supplied data. I have amended my solution to `chdir` to the data directory, to use the `chr2` chromosome name, and to create the `psl_raw` directory if it doesn't exist. Otherwise nothing has changed.

Comment: Thank you very much Borodin. It works super fast!
I was confused cause the difference in the outputs (from your script and mine) was that the lines are not in the same order.

Comment: @Vasilis: Okay great. The output is in the same order as the records appear in `chr2.best.psl`.  In the interests of supporting a fellow citizen, please get in touch on `13z844+7izlk3w26m5g@guerrillamail.net` and I will explain my situation, and what I can and cannot help with

Comment: I'm sorry, but what kind of email is that?

Comment: @Vasilis: A temporary one, although it's expired now :)